# std::unordered_map doesn't accept std::thread when it is wrapped in a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, unordered-map

If I try to save an `int` and a `std::thread` in an `std::unordered_map<int, std::thread>` everything seems to work fine.

But if I wrap the `std::unordered_map`, then I get an error in the standard library.

The error is: `no matching constructor for initialization of '_Mypair'`

Is there a way to get around this and make it work when it is wrapped?

This works:

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

void display() {}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::thread> map_;
    std::thread tempThread(&display);
    map_.emplace(0, std::move(tempThread));

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work:

**MapperWrapper.h**

```
#ifndef MAPPERWRAPPER_H
#define MAPPERWRAPPER_H

#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

template <typename KeyType, typename valueType> class MapperWrapper
{
    public:
        void add(KeyType key, valueType value)
        {
            mapper.emplace(std::make_pair(key, value));
        }

    protected:
        std::unordered_map<KeyType, valueType> mapper;
};
#endif // MAPPERWRAPPER_H
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <thread>
#include "MapperWrapper.h"

void display() {}

int main()
{
    MapperWrapper<int, std::thread> map_;
    std::thread tempThread(&display);
    map_.add(0, std::move(tempThread));

    return 0;
}
```

This generates the error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Testing (compiler: LLVM Clang Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|327|error: no matching constructor for initialization of '_Mypair' (aka 'pair<int, std::thread>')|
C:\Users\usr\Desktop\Project2\Project2\MapperWrapper.h|12|in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_pair<int &, std::thread &>' requested here|
C:\Users\usr\Desktop\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp|12|in instantiation of member function 'MapperWrapper<int, std::thread>::add' requested here|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|96|note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_copy_constructible<thread>::value' was not satisfied [with _Uty1 = int, _Uty2 = std::thread]|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|107|note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_copy_constructible<thread>::value' was not satisfied [with _Uty1 = int, _Uty2 = std::thread]|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|167|note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_constructible<thread, thread &>::value' was not satisfied [with _Other1 = int &, _Other2 = std::thread &]|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|181|note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_constructible<thread, thread &>::value' was not satisfied [with _Other1 = int &, _Other2 = std::thread &]|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|85|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|121|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '_Right', but 2 arguments were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|132|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '_Right', but 2 arguments were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|150|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 2 were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|157|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|195|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '_Right', but 2 arguments were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|209|note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '_Right', but 2 arguments were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|112|note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided|
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility|113|note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accepting the value type by value already. Since the function parameter is local, you may move it (and may as well move the key too)

```
void add(KeyType key, valueType value)
{
    mapper.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value));
}
```

There's also no need to use `std::make_pair` to emplace into the map.

If you want to be a bit more sophisticated, you may add some perfect forwarding support to `add`, so as to avoid creating superfluous intermediate objects.

```
template<typename... Args>
void add(Args&&... args)
{
    mapper.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Would there be any benefit/disadvantage to having the signature read `void add(KeyType&& key, valueType&& value)`?

Comment: @Questionable - Other than forcing a move on the caller side for all types, no. If you want to add perfect forwarding, I updated my answer.